# detecting valley regions in 1D signal

Tags: matlab

Hy Iam having a problem in detection of Valley regions of 1-Dimension signal. Actually I am recording Intensity profile in the Mid of Vessel that represents the lumen response in CTA. I want to track the valley region as shown in figure1 below(slice11-30) . I have tried alot but the local minima/maxima points does not help me to detect a relative region representing intensity dip.
[image: Image1 showing a visible intensity dip].

Moreove , second figure shows that it is not necessary to have intensity dip focusing a small region instead it can span over a large region from slice15 to 90 , where it becomes difficult to beat all the internal local peaks(maxima & minima points).[image: Large regional dip]. Any help will be appreciated.

For you convenience, I have attached the results of my processing in figure3 [image]as you have advised to use inverted Gaussian ....Kindly have a look and give me idea for moving forward.

Comment: convolve with an inverted Gaussian of similar width and find the peak in the convolution...

Comment: @bla, thankyou but I have done much work in signal processing. What I understood from your reply is to obtain first a gaussian smoothed version of signal, then perform inversion (probably 0-Gaussianvalue) and then convolve with original signal....Incase the width chosen for figure1 is 70, then the output signal is having width 140 and Iam unable to interpret results... I will be greatful if you can provide example code/ at least pseudocode for matlab based implementation....